# Uncommenting a std::cout statement gives a different result

Tags: c++

Here's the program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int removeDuplicates(int* nums, int numsSize) {
    int count=1;
    if(numsSize==1)
        return 1;
    else if(numsSize==0)
        return 0;
    for(int i=1;i<numsSize;i++)
    {
        while(i<numsSize && nums[i]==nums[i-1])
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(i==numsSize)
        {
            return count;
        }
        nums[count]=nums[i];
      //  cout << nums[i] << "-"<<std::endl;
        count++;
    }
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int nums[3]={1,1,2};
    cout <<"ans "<< removeDuplicates(nums,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note the comment

```
//  cout << nums[i] << "-"<<std::endl;
```

in the function removeDuplicates. In the current state the function returns

> 3

. On uncommenting the above statement, it returns

> 134520320

At least it does so on ideone:
https://ideone.com/5m8xPj

I see that there should be a return statement at the end of the function as well. Why doesn't the compiler return an error when it doesn't see a return statement at the end? And why does commenting/uncommenting lead to returning such weird results?

Thanks.

Comment: *warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*

Comment: Right. The compiler issues a warning. Not an error. Thanks. 
But what's with the weird results? Can we attribute it solely to 'undefined behaviour'? Or is there a reason behind it?

Comment: The reason is undefined behavior.  That's what undefined means.  You don't know what is going to happen.  Pay attention to warnings!!

Comment: Warnings are usually just as important as errors. What if `i == numsSize-1` and `nums[i] != nums[i-1]`? The while loop ends, the if never runs, and the for loop ends, returning nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the commenting/uncommenting lead to returning weird results.

Not returning anything gives you undefined behavior:

> ```
> 6.6.3  The return statement                              [stmt.return]
>
> ...
>
> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value;
> this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.
> ```

Comment: Right. Thanks. :) I'll accept the answer in another 7 minutes. I feel stupid for asking such a question right now. :P